# Почему на клиенте при входе через Chrome не работает https://animate.css/?

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, google-chrome

Почему при входе через Chrome и Mozila на [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) демо [animate - не отображается?](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1INVDuExexSnCk8f976ZS5IYbJ4kMkihU/view?usp=sharing)(
Но при входе на том же клиенте через Opera, всё - ОК.

1) При входе в режиме Инкогнито, так-же - не отображается.
2) Консоль в режиме Инкогнито - пуста (но св-ва не отображаются).
3) Переводчик - отключен.
4) Расширения - отключены.
5) Chrome - удален (разумеется и кеш с мусор), и установлен заново.
6) Антивирус - отключен.
7) Пыль с монитора - вытерта.

Что это? Мистика? Спасибо!

Comment: у меня в Хроме все работает

Comment: А у меня - нет.(

Comment: Chrome 74.0.3729.131 & Firefox 66.0.5 все работает

Comment: Ребята, я понимаю, что у вас всё работает!) Мой - Вопрос: Почему у меня не работает!( Или,  с чем связано (может быть), то - что работает у всех, у меня - не работает! Спасибо!

Comment: Поймите, ответ на ваш вопрос дать не возможно. Проблема явно в вашем *компе/браузере/прочее*, стандартные способы решения Вы уже перечислили как испробованные

Comment: Да, Спасибо. Была надежда, что кто-то сталкивался уже.

Comment: Проблема в браузерах Хром и Мозила, в Опере демо - работает.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если пользователь отключает на своем устройстве в операционной системе [анимацию](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/03/prefers-reduced-motion#remove_motion_on_operating_systems), то браузер Chrome 74 обрабатывает правило медиа запроса, которое жестко прописано в конце файла `animate.css`:

```
@media (print), (prefers-reduced-motion) {
  .animated {
    -webkit-animation: unset !important;
    animation: unset !important;
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
  }
}
```

Можете перейти на [сайт](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion#Result) и увидеть "шеволится" ли фиолетовый блок. Если не подаёт признаков жизни, то это значит что вы отключили анимацию. Можно еще на котиках [поэкспериментировать](https://prefers-reduced-motion.glitch.me).

Таким образом, на демо [animate](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) не отрабатывает событие [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event), когда анимация завершается и не удаляется класс `animated`.

PS. Windows - визуальные эффекты -> Анимированные элементы управления и элементы внутри окна.