# Не работает анимация на сайтах

Tags: вёрстка, css-animation, браузер, animate

Ребят, очень странная проблема, решения в интернете как такового не нашел
Пользуюсь сайтом animate.css, но недавно он перестал показывать анимацию,  при выборе анимации на сайте (наприме fadeIn) она должна проигрываться, у меня же просто обновляется но не показывает, такое происходит в браузер yandex и google, в IE все норм
При добавлении анимации на сайт в yandex и google она не срабатывает в IE все норм, мне кажется дело в браузере или в компе.
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/981098/256824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно ваша проблема https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/issues/928 .
В кратце - animate.css использует одно свойство, которое на WIndows зависит от системного конфига.

Для вашего компа можно включить анимации как в этом коменте https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/issues/928#issuecomment-486643786